# Jquery datatable is empty but the "No data available in table" message is not displayed

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable that gets a list of suppliers from my ASP.NET Core controller. When I get a empty list I would like my jQuery datatable to display the message "No data available in table". I do not know why it does not work.

Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image: No Message that indicates that there is no data]

Here is a screenshot of the list of supplier when empty.
[image: Console image]

As you can see there is no message indicating that "No data available in table".

I have this method in Typescript that gets the suppliers from my ASP.NET Core method

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-suppliers',
  templateUrl: './suppliers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./suppliers.component.css']
})
export class SuppliersComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  public suppliers: Supplier[];
  public supplierDeleted: boolean = false;
  public closeResult = '';

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private supplierService: SupplierService, private modalService: NgbModal, private toastr: ToastrService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      processing: true,
      responsive: true,      
      order: [[1,'asc']],
      columnDefs: [{
        targets: [0],
        orderable: false,
        width:"30px"
      },],
    };
    this.GetAllSuppliers();
  }


    GetAllSuppliers() {
        this.supplierService.getSuppliers(this.supplierDeleted).subscribe(result => {
            this.suppliers = result;
        }, error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
      }
}
```

Here is my ASP.NET Core controller:

```
    // GET api/suppliers
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<SupplierViewModel>> GetAsync(bool isDeleted)
    {
        SupplierViewModel supplierViewModel;

        List<SupplierViewModel> listSupplierViewModels = new List<SupplierViewModel>();

        var suppliers = await _supplierService.GetAllSuppliers(isDeleted);

        foreach (var supplier in suppliers)
        {
            supplierViewModel = new SupplierViewModel();
            supplierViewModel.SupplierId = supplier.SupplierId;
            supplierViewModel.Name = supplier.Name;
            supplierViewModel.PostalCode = supplier.PostalCode;
            supplierViewModel.ShoppingQuantity = supplier.ShoppingQuantity;
            supplierViewModel.SupplierReview = supplier.SupplierReview;
            supplierViewModel.Term = supplier.Term;
            supplierViewModel.WebPage = supplier.WebPage;
            supplierViewModel.Address = supplier.Address;
            supplierViewModel.City = supplier.City;
            supplierViewModel.ComponentQuantity = supplier.ComponentQuantity;
            supplierViewModel.Country = supplier.Country;
            supplierViewModel.Deleted = supplier.Deleted;

            listSupplierViewModels.Add(supplierViewModel);
        }

        return listSupplierViewModels;
    }
```

My jQuery datatable HTML markup:

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive row-border hover" *ngIf="suppliers" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a [title]="'supplier-details'" [routerLink]="['/suppliers', 0]">
          <span class="material-icons">
            add_box
          </span>
        </a>
      </th>
      <th>{{'supplier.Id' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.Name' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.Address' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.PostalCode' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.City' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.Country' | translate}}</th>
      <th>{{'supplier.Website' | translate}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers">
      <td>
        <a *ngIf="!supplierDeleted" [title]="supplier.supplierId + ' supplier-details'" [routerLink]="['/suppliers', supplier.supplierId]">
          <span class="material-icons md-18">
            edit
          </span>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="!supplierDeleted" (click)="openDelete(contentDelete, supplier.supplierId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons">
            delete
          </span>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="supplierDeleted" (click)="openRestore(contentRestore, supplier.supplierId)" href="javascript:void(0);">
          <span class="material-icons">restore</span>
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>{{ supplier.supplierId }}</td>
      <td>{{ supplier.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ supplier.address }}</td>
      <td>{{ supplier.postalCode }}</td>
      <td>{{ supplier.city }}</td>
      <td>{{ supplier.country }}</td>
      <td><a href="{{ supplier.webPage }}" target="_blank">{{ supplier.webPage }}</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Comment: Hi, could you please share more about your typescript? Also please use `console.log(this.suppliers)` to check your response data.

Comment: Hi @Rena I have added a screenshot of the list of suppliers when empty. I have also added more code of my typescript file. Is this sufficient for you. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with "Jquery datatable". But try this,

```
<tr *ngIf="suppliers.length == 0">
  <td colspan="8">
     No data available in table
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the template file, just check the "suppliers" array length to check for any suppliers.

Comment: It is a intresting idea. However it does not fully fix the problem since when I sort the datatable the data reappers for some reason.